# "effort in answering" or "effort for answering"?

Tags: prepositions

I want to thank someone for answering my question by appreciating his effort. What do have I to say?

> 1. Thanks for your effort in answering.
> 2. Thanks for your effort for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first of those is correct, the second not. There are other options, but that one isn't wrong or particularly strange. "Thanks for the effort you put into this answer" would be more likely what I'd write, if I wanted to note the effort. However, "thanks for answering" is perfectly sufficient, generally.